# Easiest ways to loop through an xarray

Tags: pandas, python-xarray

I have a table like this:

this:
[image]

This picture only shows one permutation of acct_desc_program_code and product.  You can imagine I have hundreds of them.  I want to loop through every permutation of acct_desc, program_code, product and for each permutation get a series of sum for that permutation etc. So I can stick it into a panda aware model.  I thought maybe xarray would do it if I make acct_desc, program_code, product and index on eomonth.  As there's no easy tutorial, I thought I'd ask how before reinventing the wheel.  This seems like such a common use case.  Oh, and I'd like to set sum to 0 if there's a missing eomonth.

Alternatively, I could just handle every permutation in a select distinct in postgre and get the data adn do the analysis in a big loop.  The database is close, so there's not to much of a penalty if the wire is too hot.  Still, it just seems like it should be more efficient to handle the separation of the data right in an xarray locally.

Comment: You say this is actual data, but then you're talking about datetimes and missing months.  Can you please create a [mcve] with a clearly defined problem and example input/output?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, don't use xarray.  This was my answer

```
df['eomonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['eomonth'])
ddf = df.drop(['eomonth','sum'],axis=1).drop_duplicates()
    for _, row in ddf.iterrows():
        x = df[(df['customer']==row['customer']) & (df['acct_desc']==row['acct_desc'])&(df['product']==row['product']) & (df['program_code']==row['program_code'])]
        #do stuff with x
```

I can never format on this thing.  There has to be a tutorial.  Anyway, I don't think xarrays were meant for this, easier to just filter a million times than build it out along the dimensions